# Convert into map using java 8 (split spring and make key, other value of object as value)

Tags: java

My `Order` class is as follows:

```java
class Order {
    String orderId;
    String executionId;

    Order(String orderId, String executionId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
        this.executionId = executionId;
    }

    public String getOrderId() {
        return orderId;
    }

    public void setOrderId(String orderId) {
        this.orderId = orderId;
    }

    public String getExecutionId() {
        return executionId;
    }

    public void setExecutionId(String executionId) { 
        this.executionId = executionId; 
    }
}
```

```java
List<Order> orders =
                Arrays.asList( new Order("2", "23,21,25"),
                        new Order("4", "22,24"),
                        new Order("6", "27"),
                        new Order("2", "28,30"),
                        new Order("4", "29"),
                        new Order("5", "26"));
```

I need a map object output according to the below structure to obtain the orders related to the executions

```
Map<String, String> = {"23","2"},{"21","2"},{"25","2"},{"22","4"},{"24","4"},{"27","6"},{"28","2"},{"30","2"},{"29","4"},{"26","5"};
```

the comma-separated value should be considered a map key and other value of the object should be value.

Comment: Can you share the `Order` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for something like below -

```
    Map<String, String> flatMap = new HashMap<>();

    orders.forEach(order -> {
        String k = order.orderId;
        String values = order.executionId;

        for (String v : values.split(",")) {
            flatMap.put(v, k);
        }

    });
```

Not an oneliner approach but readability wise preferred to me.

Here is the less preferred approach -

```
Map<String, String> flatMap = orders.stream()
        .map(order -> Arrays.stream(order.executionId.split(","))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), x -> order.orderId)))
        .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
        List<Order> orders = Arrays.asList(
                new Order("2", "23,21,25"),
                new Order("4", "22,24"), new Order("6", "27"),
                new Order("2", "28,30"), new Order("4", "29"),
                new Order("8", "26"), //<-- added this for demo
                new Order("5", "26"));

        Map<String, String> map = orders.stream()
                .flatMap(order -> Arrays
                        .stream(order.getExecutionId()
                                .split(","))
                        .map(a -> new String[] { a,
                                order.getOrderId() }))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(info -> info[0], info -> info[1],
                        (value, oId) -> value + "," + oId,
                        LinkedHashMap::new));

        System.out.println(map);
```

It prints the following:

> {23=2, 21=2, 25=2, 22=4, 24=4, 27=6, 
>    28=2, 30=2, 29=4, 26=8,5}

Notice the last entry.  That is the merge function in case you end up with the same
key for different values.  It concatenates them. If you don't have this situation, leaving it in will not cause a problem.

Here is the same result using nested loops and the `map.merge` method which is also Java 8.

```
        Map<String,String> map2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        for (Order order : orders) {
            for (String eId : order.getExecutionId().split(",")) {
                map2.merge(eId, order.getOrderId(), (value,oId)->  value + "," + oId);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(map2);
```